# Saving OpenVPN credentials in terminal

Tags: linux, ubuntu, vpn, openvpn

I would like to save credentials when using OpenVPN in terminal. Is this possible?

I have using Gnome's network manager OpenVPN plugin and it is throwing errors with this particular VPN but using OpenVPN via the terminal works just fine except that should there be a disconnection, OpenVPN cannot automatically reconnect because it doesn't have the credentials. So is there a way to save them, perhaps through flag when running the command:

```
openvpn config.ovpn
```

Answer (score 0):

I found a very simple undocumented way to save credentials directly inside .ovpn file.

https://openvpn.net/community-resources/reference-manual-for-openvpn-2-4/

instead of :

```
auth-user-pass credentials.txt
```

insert :

```
<auth-user-pass>
user
password
</auth-user-pass>
```

also i got a "missing external certificate" error with NordVPN, fixed (MAYBE UNSAFE) by inserting the line below into the .ovpn file:

```
setenv CLIENT_CERT 0
```

EDIT :

I was messing around to get rid of the NordVPN client :)

Here's my article if someone is interested :

https://blog.ilusio.dev/goodbye-nordvpn-desktop-client/

Answer (score 0):

you can check this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38869427/openvpn-on-linux-passing-username-and-password-in-command-line)

```
MacOs 14.0, M1
openvpn --version 2.6.8
```

1- go to your config folder (the folder you usually save your configs).

2- create a pass.txt file in there like this:

```
cd ~/Documnets
mkdir configs
cd configs
touch pass.txt
sudo nano pass.txt
```

and paste the username and password of OpenVpn

```
[USERNAME]
[PASSWORD]
```

(if you like you can create another folder inside config with the name of openvpn :-) )

2- create an alias in your profile for me it was (.zprofile) with the following text.

```
alias [ShortCut/ALias Name]="sudo openvpn --config [PATH_TO_THE_.OVPN]/[openvpnFileName].ovpn --auth-user-pass [PATH_TO_THE_pass.txt]"
```

then hit x and y to save and quit.

if you follow step one your path should be something like this:

```
~/Documents/configs/config.ovpn
~/Documents/configs/pass.txt
```

final script

```
alias ovpn="sudo openvpn --config ~/Documents/configs/config.ovpn --auth-user-pass ~/Documents/configs/pass.txt"
```

3- restart the terminal.

any where in teminal type `ovpn` hit enter and you will be connect to your VPN. (beacuse of sudo you might asked for a password)

Answer (score -1):

Add your username and password to a plain text file (eg login.file) and use the  "auth-user-pass /path/to/login.file" directive to your config.ovpn file (or pass --auth-user-pass /path/to/login.file)

The format of login.file is simply

```
  username
  password
```